# PHP session resetting

Tags: php, session, session-state

I have PHP 5.6 running on IIS 8.5. I used this test log:

`echo '<p>'.sizeof($_SESSION).' - '.session_id().' - '.ini_get('session.cookie_domain').'</p>';`

With it I see that `$_SESSION` has some elements, `cookie_domain` is properly set in php.ini as my domain, but `session_id()` has a different string on each page load.  `session_start()` is being called on every page load.

Any idea on what I can do to make session persistent?

`$sessionfile = ini_get('session.save_path') . '/' . 'sess_'.session_id();` shows where the session file is. I'm able to open it and data is there. Indeed it's something in the creation of each session, not in saving their files.

Is it possible that some IIS setting or some asp is reseting the session?

Comment: You are calling this code AFTER `session_start();` right?

Comment: Yes, session_start() is one of the first things run.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur most times if you don't have permissions to store the session in your IIS. I had the same problem before a long time. To correct the permissions or the session path solved my problem.

Comment: I get it. But I believe that's not the problem, because I'm able to find the session file and open it and data is saved on that file. Something is resetting the session, maybe the cookie that stores its reference.